# Add label to DropzoneJS upload queue

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js, dropzone

I am building a project in which a user needs to upload a primary image and secondary image. I am using DropzoneJS to accomplish this. Here is my code:

```js
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var image_width = 380,
  image_height = 507;
var photo_upload_primary = new Dropzone("#photo_upload_primary", {
  maxFilesize: 1,
  maxFiles: 1,
  acceptedFiles: "image/*",
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  url: "upload.php",
  previewsContainer: "#formfiles",
  previewTemplate: $("#formtemplate").html(),
  dictFileTooBig: "Image is too large ({{filesize}}MiB). Max file size is {{maxFilesize}}MiB.",
  dictInvalidFileType: "This file is not an image.",
  dictMaxFilesExceeded: "You have already uploaded a primary product image.",
  dictDefaultMessage: "Click or drop primary product image here",
  success: function(file, response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(file, response) {
    $.notify({
      message: response
    }, {
      type: "danger"
    });

    this.removeFile(file);
  },
  init: function() {
    this.on("thumbnail", function(file) {
      if (file.width !== image_width || file.height !== image_height) {
        file.rejectDimensions();
      } else {
        file.acceptDimensions();
      }
    });
  },
  accept: function(file, done) {
    file.acceptDimensions = done;
    file.rejectDimensions = function() {
      done("Product image resolution outside of specifications. Resolution must be " + image_width + "px x " + image_height + "px");
    };
  },
  renameFile: function(file) {
    var ext = file.name.substring(file.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    var newName = 'primary.' + ext;
    return newName;
  },
});

var photo_upload_secondary = new Dropzone("#photo_upload_secondary", {
  maxFilesize: 1,
  maxFiles: 1,
  acceptedFiles: "image/*",
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  url: "upload.php",
  previewsContainer: "#formfiles",
  previewTemplate: $("#formtemplate").html(),
  dictFileTooBig: "Image is too large ({{filesize}}MiB). Max file size is {{maxFilesize}}MiB.",
  dictInvalidFileType: "This file is not an image.",
  dictMaxFilesExceeded: "You have already uploaded a secondary product image.",
  dictDefaultMessage: "Click or drop secondary product image here",
  success: function(file, response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(file, response) {
    $.notify({
      message: response
    }, {
      type: "danger"
    });
    this.removeFile(file);
  },
  init: function() {
    //this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
    //    file.mycustomname = "my-new-name" + file.name;
    //console.log(file);
    //});
    this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
      file.previewTemplate.setAttribute('id', responseText[0].id);

      $(".dz-id:last-child").html("hi!");

      file.previewElement.html = "hh";

    });
    this.on("thumbnail", function(file) {
      if (file.width !== image_width || file.height !== image_height) {
        file.rejectDimensions();
      } else {
        file.acceptDimensions();
      }
    });
  },
  accept: function(file, done) {
    file.acceptDimensions = done;
    file.rejectDimensions = function() {
      done("Product image resolution outside of specifications. Resolution must be " + image_width + "px x " + image_height + "px");
    };
  },
  renameFile: function(file) {
    var ext = file.name.substring(file.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    var newName = 'secondary.' + ext;
    return newName;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/dropzone.js"></script>

<h4>Image Upload</h4>
<form>
  <div id="photo_upload_primary" action="/file-upload" class="dropzone m-b-15"></div>

  <div id="photo_upload_secondary" action="/file-upload" class="dropzone"></div>

  <!-- Preview -->
  <div class="mt-3" id="formfiles"></div>
  <!-- File preview template -->
  <div class="d-none" id="formtemplate">
    <div class="card mb-3">
      <div class="p-2">
        <div class="row align-items-start">
          <div class="col-auto">
            <img data-dz-thumbnail src="#" class="avatar border rounded">
          </div>
          <div class="col pl-0">
            <a href="#" class="text-muted font-weight-bold" data-dz-name></a>
            <a href="#" class="text-muted font-weight-bold dz-id" data-dz-id></a>
            <p class="mb-0"><small data-dz-size></small>
              <small class="d-block text-danger" data-dz-errormessage></small></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-auto pt-2">
            <a class="btn-lg text-danger" href="#" data-dz-remove><i class="icon-trash-2"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<small id="dropzoneHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Required image resolution is 380px x 507px with a maximum file size of 1MB</small>
<!-- end: File preview template -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-shadow" onclick="upload()">Add Product</button>
```

I would like to label the files in the upload queue as "Primary" and "Secondary" next to the respective file and thumbnail. I am having trouble finding documentation on how this can be done in DropZoneJS. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitively need 2 templates. One with "primary template", another with "secondary template". But in order to avoid creating 2 HTML templates you can use a template generator like this:

```
genTemplate = (tmpName) => {
  let tmp = $("#formtemplate").clone()
  tmp.find(".template-number").html(tmpName)
  return tmp.html()
}
```

That way you can easily choose the template string for each one without rewriting the HTML.

```js
genTemplate = (tmpName) => {
  let tmp = $("#formtemplate").clone()
  tmp.find(".template-number").html(tmpName)
  return tmp.html()
}

Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var image_width = 380,
  image_height = 507;
var photo_upload_primary = new Dropzone("#photo_upload_primary", {
  maxFilesize: 1,
  maxFiles: 1,
  acceptedFiles: "image/*",
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  url: "upload.php",
  previewsContainer: "#formfiles",
  previewTemplate: genTemplate("Primary template"),
  dictFileTooBig: "Image is too large ({{filesize}}MiB). Max file size is {{maxFilesize}}MiB.",
  dictInvalidFileType: "This file is not an image.",
  dictMaxFilesExceeded: "You have already uploaded a primary product image.",
  dictDefaultMessage: "Click or drop primary product image here",
  success: function(file, response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(file, response) {
    /*$.notify({
      message: response
    }, {
      type: "danger"
    });
    this.removeFile(file);*/
  },
  init: function() {
    this.on("thumbnail", function(file) {
      if (file.width !== image_width || file.height !== image_height) {
        file.rejectDimensions();
      } else {
        file.acceptDimensions();
      }
    });
  },
  accept: function(file, done) {
    file.acceptDimensions = done;
    file.rejectDimensions = function() {
      done("Product image resolution outside of specifications. Resolution must be " + image_width + "px x " + image_height + "px");
    };
  },
  renameFile: function(file) {
    var ext = file.name.substring(file.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    var newName = 'primary.' + ext;
    return newName;
  },
});

var photo_upload_secondary = new Dropzone("#photo_upload_secondary", {
  maxFilesize: 1,
  maxFiles: 1,
  acceptedFiles: "image/*",
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  url: "upload.php",
  previewsContainer: "#formfiles",
  previewTemplate: genTemplate("Secondary template"),
  dictFileTooBig: "Image is too large ({{filesize}}MiB). Max file size is {{maxFilesize}}MiB.",
  dictInvalidFileType: "This file is not an image.",
  dictMaxFilesExceeded: "You have already uploaded a secondary product image.",
  dictDefaultMessage: "Click or drop secondary product image here",
  success: function(file, response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(file, response) {
    /*$.notify({
      message: response
    }, {
      type: "danger"
    });
    this.removeFile(file);*/
  },
  init: function() {
    //this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
    //    file.mycustomname = "my-new-name" + file.name;
    //console.log(file);
    //});
    this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
      file.previewTemplate.setAttribute('id', responseText[0].id);

      $(".dz-id:last-child").html("hi!");

      file.previewElement.html = "hh";

    });
    this.on("thumbnail", function(file) {
      if (file.width !== image_width || file.height !== image_height) {
        file.rejectDimensions();
      } else {
        file.acceptDimensions();
      }
    });
  },
  accept: function(file, done) {
    file.acceptDimensions = done;
    file.rejectDimensions = function() {
      done("Product image resolution outside of specifications. Resolution must be " + image_width + "px x " + image_height + "px");
    };
  },
  renameFile: function(file) {
    var ext = file.name.substring(file.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    var newName = 'secondary.' + ext;
    return newName;
  }
});
```

```css
.card {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/dropzone.js"></script>

<h4>Image Upload</h4>
<form>
  <div id="photo_upload_primary" action="/file-upload" class="dropzone m-b-15"></div>

  <div id="photo_upload_secondary" action="/file-upload" class="dropzone"></div>

  <!-- Preview -->
  <div class="mt-3" id="formfiles"></div>
  <!-- File preview template -->
  <div class="d-none" id="formtemplate">
    <div class="card mb-3">
      <div class="p-2">
        <div class="row align-items-start">
          <div class="col-auto">
            <img data-dz-thumbnail src="#" class="avatar border rounded">
          </div>
          <div class="col pl-0">
            <h2 class="template-number"></h2>
            <a href="#" class="text-muted font-weight-bold" data-dz-name></a>
            <a href="#" class="text-muted font-weight-bold dz-id" data-dz-id></a>
            <p class="mb-0"><small data-dz-size></small>
              <small class="d-block text-danger" data-dz-errormessage></small></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-auto pt-2">
            <a class="btn-lg text-danger" href="#" data-dz-remove><i class="icon-trash-2"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<small id="dropzoneHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Required image resolution is 380px x 507px with a maximum file size of 1MB</small>
<!-- end: File preview template -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-shadow" onclick="upload()">Add Product</button>
```